# Omitting USB 2.0 pins on a USB 3.1 connection

Tags: usb, usb-c, slip-ring

I am in a situation where my project requires the use of a slip ring so wires can freely rotate. I will be limited to the number of wires that can run through it, which is a total of 12.

I have a USB 3.0 device that I want to connect through the slip ring using USB-A 3.1 and USB-C breakouts on each end. I don't need to have the redundant row/reversible plug option so I will only be working with one row (A1-A12). The device I am connecting will *only be using a 3.0 port, never 2.0*. Through some reading, I found that the D pins shown below exist for USB 2.0 compatibility:

[image: USB C Connections]

It seems that they are only there to transfer data if the plug is connected to a USB 2.0 port. Can I safely omit the USB 2.0 pins in this situation? Doing so would free up two wires on the slip ring which are important for connecting another device.

Comment: Slip rings are unlikely to work at the high speeds of the super-speed pins.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/297031/usb-3-x-ss-enumeration/297373

Comment: Why does this site get so many questions of people trying to abuse USB connectors? If you cannot connect all wires needed for reversing the plug, use another connector, e.g. a Type A Super Speed connector or a custom plug altogether.

Comment: Why do you believe that the slip ring is capable of differentially transmitting 2.5-5 Ghz signals? If not, your arrangement might be useless.

Comment: And you don't need 12 wires, 6 is enough. Maybe two more grounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to support BC1.2 and high speed 480Mbps, you can ignore differential pairs of USB 2.0.